# IE9 debugging in VisualStudio Cache pages incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, dynamic-data

There may be a setting I am missing somewhere, but I am completely dumbfounded by this issue. I have a dynamic data web site that is using role based permissions to limit the content a specific user can view, edit and delete. When the user first logs in and is redirected to the default page, it displays all of the correct tables for that users role. After clicking on any of the available tables, then clicking the browser back button, the default page will display **every** table within the database regardless of what the users role dictates. I am dumbfounded because at no point is there a view of every table available to any users role yet somehow ie9 managed to cache this imaginary version of the page. I know that this must be a cache issue because page_load on the default page is not triggered when the back arrow is clicked. If I refresh the default page it will be displayed correctly again.

I am working with a master page and explicitly turned off every form of caching I could think of in its page load.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

One other thing to note is that this only seem to be an issue with ie9 when I test the site in ff, chrome or safari things work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the role of the user who logs in in a session variable and then show the required data(table or whatever) based on that value.If the data is shown based on the user's role in the session then i don't think you will have any problem. Also you can disable the cache by giving `Response.Cache.SetNoStore();` at the page load function.